# Hide page for user logged and redirect for profile?

Tags: redirect

I have a page on wordpress, that after you enter is redirected to your profile page. So far so good.

However, after the user logged in would have had no more access to the homepage. I've hid the "HOME" menu, but if for some reason it access the home page, I would like him to be redirected to their profile page.

Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of user role do you want to redirect from home to the profile page? basically anyone including admin? and what did you try so far?

Comment: All users are redirected. I've tried plugins, but without success.

Comment: See Gareth's answer below. It's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but should work

```
add_action('wp', function() {
  $url = home_url('my-profile/'); // profile url here
  if(is_user_logged_in()){
    if(is_front_page() || is_home()){
      wp_redirect($url);
      exit;
    }
  }
});
```

Edit: I hooked into `wp` so the functions in the conditional will work. Add the above snippet of code to your child theme's functions file, after you edit the `$url` on line:2

Comment: This should be hooked into `init` or 'wp' I guess

Comment: In that file I put this code? And how will I select the profile address if multiple users are?

Comment: You can put it into a function and run on init (as Samuel said) or you can put it into your header.php before everything else......

Comment: I'm not knowing perform this function. This is frustrating.

Comment: this does use anonymous functions which might not work if the OP is using an older version of PHP tho

Comment: True if running PHP v. less than 5.5.* I assume. I edited again, just in case. Sorry to bother with edits.

Comment: Yes, it's almost certain. The problem is that it redirects to /profile and gives not displayed page. I would not like to put the specific address profile, and yes, the function will serve to all user profiles.

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Hello. The question is still open and unsolved. Can someone help me?